# Passing a variable into a callback function but it's coming up as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, maps, azure-maps

I'm trying to pass a variable into a callback function that's apart of an event listener for Azure Maps but that variable comes up as 'undefined' once I console.log the variable in the other function. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Am I passing the variable to the callback function the wrong way?

```
loadData = () => {
let dataSource = new window.atlas.source.DataSource('map', {
        cluster: true,
        clusterRadius: clusterRadiusLevel,
        clusterMaxZoom: maxClusterZoomLevel
      });
  maps.event.add('click', layer, (e,dataSource) => this.clickedCluster(e,dataSource)
}

clickedCluster = (e,dataSource) => {
console.log(dataSource)
}
```

there's definitely more to the loadData function but gave enough information of what I'm trying to do. The console.log in clickedCluster keeps coming back undefined. I know it's not undefined because I console logged the variable inside the loadData function and I'm getting an object back containing all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing a closing paren on the `maps.event...` line.

Secondly, don't include `dataSource` as the 2nd param to your anonymous arrow function on the same line:

```
let loadData = () => {
    let dataSource = new window.atlas.source.DataSource('map', {
        cluster: true,
        clusterRadius: clusterRadiusLevel,
        clusterMaxZoom: maxClusterZoomLevel
    });
    maps.event.add('click', layer, e => this.clickedCluster(e, dataSource));
};

let clickedCluster = (e, dataSource) => {
    console.log(dataSource)
};
```

The highlight why this is correct, take a look at this simpler example

```js
let callback = a => console.log('callback', a);

let x = 'hello';

let caller1 = x => callback(x);
let caller2 = () => callback(x);

caller1(); // undefined
caller2(); // 'hello'
```

This is called "shadowing" btw ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)).

Comment: You might want to note that the callback parameters are not determined by our code, because we are not the one who runs the callback. It's out of our control. So you have to look at the docs to see what parameters the callback function will accept and use only those parameters.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I always thought the variables had to be called as a param in an arrow function before passing it to the callback. I learned something new today.

Comment: @Rchan If the above response helped/resolved your query, please accept the response as answer.